# Find column index where row value is greater than zero in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data set as follows:

```
    A   B   C
R1  1   0   1
R2  0   1   0
R3  0   0   0
```

I want to add another column in data set named index such that it gives column names for each row where the column value is greater than zero. The result I want is as follows:

```
    A   B   C   Index
R1  1   0   1   A,C
R2  0   1   0   B
R3  0   0   0   NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using base:

use apply to go over rows, find elements that are equal to one and paste together the corresponding column names:

```
df$Index <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(colnames(df)[which(x == 1)], collapse = ", "))
```

`df$Index <-` crate a new column called `Index` where the result of the operation will be held

`apply` - applies a function over rows and/or columns of a matrix/data frame

`1` - specify that the function should be applied to rows (`2` - means over columns)

`function(x)` an unnamed function which is further defined - `x` corresponds to each row

`which(x == 1)` which elements of a row are equal to `1` output is `TRUE/FALSE`

`colnames(df)` - names of the columns of the data frame

`colnames(df)[which(x == 1]` - subsets the column names which are `TRUE` for the expression `which(x == 1)`

`paste` with `collapse = ", "` - collapse a character vector (in this case a vector of column names that we acquired before) into a string where each element will be separated by `,`.

now replace empty entries with NA

```
df$Index[df$Index == ""] <- NA_character_
```

here is how the output looks like

```
#output
  sample A B C Index
1     R1 1 0 1  A, C
2     R2 0 1 0     B
3     R3 0 0 0  <NA>
```

data:

```
structure(list(sample = structure(1:3, .Label = c("R1", "R2", 
"R3"), class = "factor"), A = c(1L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 1L, 0L
), C = c(1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sample", "A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 provided explanation in the edit, if anything is unclear please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different flavored `apply()`solution:

```
df$index <- apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x), toString(names(df)[x == 1]), NA))

   A B C index
R1 1 0 1  A, C
R2 0 1 0     B
R3 0 0 0  <NA>
```

data:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    A = c(1L, 0L, 0L), 
    B = c(0L, 1L, 0L),
    C = c(1L, 0L, 0L)
  ), 
  row.names = paste0('R', 1:3), 
  class = "data.frame"
)
```